# Go around short circuit protection

Tags: lithium-ion, peltier

I recently bought a lithium-ion battery that has a built in protection for short circuit. I want to power a thermoelectric cooler with it. But when i connect it to the battery it seems that the protection for short circuit kicks in and won't power the cooler. Does anybody know how can i get around this problem? I have tested both the cooler and the battery and they both work, just not with each other.

Link to battery: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13112

Link to thermoelectric cooler: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10080

Comment: I'm sorry but this is one of those questions that if you have to ask, you probably shouldnt be doing it. RC LiPo batteries tend to have a much higher current discharge rating than standard li-ions.

Comment: Information that should have been included in question: (1) Battery make, model, capacity, voltage, current and link to datasheet. (2) Thermoelectric cooler make, model, voltage, current and link to datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the question with links to the battery and the cooler.

Comment: The 110 mAh battery is limited to 2C discharge, or 220 mA. This is a tiny amount of current for a TEC -- not a good match.

Comment: You will find that all Li+ / LiPo batteries sold at retail (if they meet IEC 62133) have short circuit protection (and overvoltage protection) *for your own safety*; do not attempt to bypass it. Without that protection, they can be spectacularly pyrotechnic. That said, you clearly need a battery with the necessary current discharge specifications.

Comment: If you manage to bypass the short circuit protection, the battery will explode in your face and you will die. (Well okay, you probably won't *die*)

Answer (score 7):

The battery spec says:

> What sets this battery apart from our other 110mAh battery is that fact that it was truly made for e-textiles projects. With no risk to short out and a low current delivery, the E-Textiles Battery **will cut off in the range of 240-380mA** making this the safest option to power electronics sewn into pieces of fabric.

The cooler spec says:

> lmax - **7 A**.

That battery is not capable of powering that cooler.

Comment: Theoretically, the battery should power the cooler for 40 seconds at 70% efficiency.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Theoretically, the battery should catch fire if you try, because it has a maximum current rating.

Comment: @PandaLion98 *Theoretically*, the battery should catch fire if you try, because it *theoretically* has a maximum current rating.